# Is using diodes in this scenario a common good practice?

Tags: batteries, diodes, protection

I will purchase two rechargeable 12V 50Ah batteries. The batteries will be same model same type and will be fresh. There is a non-technical reason for not using a single 12V 100Ah thats why this question is related to connecting two batteries in parallel.

I have read that even the batteries are same type and both are fully charged, their inner resistance ect might differ and I have encountered an example which uses two diodes as shown below:
[image]

So imagine at the beginning the batteries are fresh and fully charged. But by the time one might differ than the other. Besides after they are discharged and if a person charges them again. There might be risk because the batteries might not be charged exactly same.

My questions are:

1-) Is this way of connecting batteries with diodes common and good in practice?

2-) Which parameter from the data-sheet of a Schottky diode should I consider if the nominal current drawn will be 1A?

Comment: (1) it's reasonable, (2) the current rating, and the forward voltage at 1A. Presumably you have an independent charging circuit for each battery.

Comment: "Presumably you have an independent charging circuit for each battery" Is this a problem to connect them in parallel?  Why did you remind it? Just curious.

Comment: @user16307 He says that because you won't be able to charge through your + terminal with the diodes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do this as it complicates charging for example.

What **I** would do is **balance** the two batteries, that means discharging/charging  them so that they will have **the same voltage** and then connect them directly in parallel.

This balancing can be done by:

- connect both battery's - (negative) poles together directly
- connect the + (positive) together with a resistor or (car) light bulb in between. A 10 ohms 1 W resistor would do the job.
- Leave that connected for a couple of hours or a day and measure the voltages of the batteries. When they're almost the same you can safely connect the two batteries permanently in parallel.

Comment: Is the resistor or bulb to limit the current?

Comment: Yes indeed to limit the current.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this, you MUST charge them separately.

With that said, I've used the approach on multiple aerospace R&D projects, including nearly a dozen suborbital missile shots. The diode must be rated to carry the full load current, with a reverse voltage rating of the battery voltage at full charge (plus about 50% as a safety factor). Depending on system factors, it may be necessary to heat-sink the diodes. You can get dual common-cathode diodes in a power package like TO220, which may make packaging easier.

Comment: If I follow Bimpelrekkie's method do I still need the diodes?

Comment: No, my solution is completely without diodes. After balancing and connecting in parallel you can treat the 2 x 50 Ah batteries as if it is one single 100 Ah battery.

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem with charging together in circuit is?

Comment: @jarmond - If one battery is weaker than the other, charging them with a single charger will charge up the weak battery, while the strong one will be undercharged.

Comment: To be more clear, if you charge them both at the same time with the same charger, then the charging connection must put the batteries in parallel with each other.  That is exactly what you were trying to avoid in the first place.