# Supplying an input to a power supply from two batteries without connecting them in parallel

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, dc-dc-converter

I want to power a buck converter with two 84V batteries without having them connected in parallel.

At the output of the buck converter is a relay circuit that switches between the two batteries to drive a motor, one battery at a time. That is, when one battery is depleted, the motor is connected to the second battery.

The circuit at the output of the buck converter is as follows:

[image]

The buck converter is to be powered by one of the 84V batteries.

I want to design a circuit whereby the input of the buck converter can be from either of the batteries, that is, incase one battery is depleted, the buck converter's input can be taken from the other battery.

Comment: Set a relay held open by battery 1 that isolates battery 2. Once battery 1 is below its threshold voltage then the relay closes, changing the supply from batt 1 to batt 2. Needs a changeover relay.

Comment: @Solar Mike pls elaborate. where will the coil and contact terminals of the changeover relay be connected?

Comment: Why din’t you make a copy of your circuit with a changeover relay and attempt the connections - then we can correct what may be needed.

Comment: Whilst you are redrawing the circuit, please remove the red dots, they are confusing. It looks as if pins 4,3&2 are all connected together on the 4-way block at the left. The 2 red dots on the wire coming from pin 1 signify nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to design a circuit whereby the input of the buck converter can
> be from either of the batteries, that is, in case one battery is
> depleted, the buck converter's input can be taken from the other
> battery.*

The input voltage supply to the buck regulator can be fed via a diode from one battery and also fed via a diode from the other battery. This means that the battery that is producing the highest voltage, feeds the buck converter: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361572/is-using-diodes-in-this-scenario-a-common-good-practice).

Comment: thank you for your help not only here, but you have also helped me in many occasions. That being said, can I use reverse polarity protection circuit instead of the diodes to lower the power losses? will that have the same effect of avoiding connecting the batteries in parallel? eg if I use a pmosfet with a very low series resistance?

Comment: @p_karis feel free to take that diagram and add on one channel. You can then edit your question (at the end) and say you are putting in a new picture because you've changed the question.